# Boolean Functions in C "control may reach end of non-void function" error

Tags: c, function, boolean, cs50

i'm always getting "control may reach end of non-void function" on the boolean function when compiling the code and don't know what's causing this.

Here's the code, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool digit_validation (string s);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    
    if((argc == 2) && (digit_validation(argv[1]) == true))
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("%i\n", key);
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }

}

bool digit_validation (string s)
{
for (int i = 0, lenght = strlen (s); i < lenght; i++ )
{
    if(isdigit(s[i]))
    {
        return true;
        break;
    }
    
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does your `main` function `return` anything?

Comment: If `for` is not entered at all, your function won't return a value (length is `0`).

Comment: I'm especially confused by your `for` statement that has an `if` in it where both of them exit. Why even loop if you're going to bail for sure on the first iteration?

Comment: Your `digit_validation` function won't execute `return` statement when `s` is an empty string.

Comment: PSA: It's `length` not `lenght`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second function is just a bit jumbled up, but it's an easy fix:

```
bool digit_validation(string s) {
  size_t length = strlen(s);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (isdigit(s[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }        

  return false;
}
```

As others have observed your loop could have been skipped and that would result in hitting the end of the function without returning anything. As a general rule you want to structure your code so the exit points are obvious, and that was not the case in your original.

This doesn't detect "all digits" yet, you'll still have to fix that by inverting the logic:

```
bool digit_validation(string s) {
  size_t length = strlen(s);

  if (!length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!isdigit(s[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }        

  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is C, not C++. Also why are you using `int` for `i` while using `size_t` for `length`?

Comment: @MikeCAT I really, really, **really** despise CS50.

Comment: Also `,` in the `for` should be `;`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Fixed.

Comment: From the context of the code, `digit_validation` should return true iff `s` is a string containing one or more digits and only digits. The code in this answer returns true if `s` contains a digit, even if it contains non-digits.

Comment: Why leave the bad code in the answer? Deleting it will improve the answer.

Comment: Also FYI: The reason the other answer uses `isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])` instead of `isdigit(s[i])` is the C standard does not define the behavior of `isdigit` for negative values, which can occur if `char` is signed. (As far as I know, CS50 defines `string` as `char *`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil The first chunk solves the original problem of return values, the second is just other bug fixes.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is warning that the function `digit_validation` could potentially end up "falling off"  of the function - without returning any value. If the caller uses the value, as it happens in your code, it results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For example, if you pass an empty string `""`, then `length` is 0 and the `for` loop is not entered at all.

`digit_validation` also has other problems.

- If you pass a null pointer, `strlen` would be problematic.
- It doesn't actually validate that *all* characters are digits; as soon as the first digit is found, the function returns without checking the rest.

It could be fixed as:

```
bool digit_validation (string s)
{
    if (!s || !s[0]) return false;

    for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {
        if(!isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) return false;
    }
  
    return true;
}
```

Couple of points:

- The argument of `isdigit` (and all the ctype functions in general) need to be cast to `unsigned char` to avoid [undefined behaviour in case of negative values](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1).
- Given that `s` is a *string*, you can avoid using `strlen` to calculate the length and instead use the sentinel null byte (`strlen` will check the same, after all).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Got any idea how can i validate that all characters are digits ?

Comment: Updated with how you could fix those issues in your function.